# Page url is different in IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I have this wired situation using JQuery. I have three pages on my website.

1. index.html
2. business.html
3. operation.htmls

When i open business.html URL is **firefox**, it opens like this

```
http://localhost:9090/Operational/business.html
```

When i click an button on this page called 'operation.html', it open a new page with follow address

```
http://localhost:9090/Operational/operation.html
```

All fine till now. But when I open the same operation.html page in IE 9, the URL is something unusal :

```
http://localhost:9090/Operational/business.html#/Operational/Operations.html
```

Why is this so? Can somebody put some light on this? I am stuck :P @!!!!

**adding more details**

I am using a development tool called tiggzi.
here is the anchoring part of the code.

```
$('#j_2 [name="mobilenavbaritem4_141"]').die().live({
    click: function () {
        if (!$(this).attr('disabled')) {
            Tiggr.navigateTo('Operations', {
                transition: 'slide',
                reverse: false
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Will you update your post with the HTML/JS that creates the link?

Comment: Post the HTML for business.html

Comment: please add in your question the html of the element/tag within the header `j_2` with the name `name="mobilenavbaritem4_141"`. This is what this jQuery is trying to access

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the code, we can only speculate, but it is very likely that the page has JavaScript which updates the content and then uses [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to set a bookmarkable URI.

IE9 doesn't support the history API, so it falls back to using a fragment identifier as a hack.

If someone were to visit `http://localhost:9090/Operational/business.html#/Operational/Operations.html` directly, the server would deliver the content of `business.html` and then the JavaScript would request the content of `Operations.html` and replace it.

Comment: To add, If you wanted to remove the `#/Operational/Operations.html` from the url and prevent it from being added back, you would have to disable the history api you are using in browsers that don't support pushstate, but the content will no longer be ajax-loaded.

Comment: @Quentin - I dont think if I understand you (sorry. im a naive this).
do yo uwnat me to post the JS or HTML??
i can do that

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you probably have `onclick` on an `Anchor tag` as well as working `href`.

If thats the case, put `return false;` at within the end of the onclick.

Comment: can you post your Anchor tag which is causing this?

Comment: $('#j_2 [name="mobilenavbaritem4_141"]').die().live({
            click: function() {
                if (!$(this).attr('disabled')) {
                    Tiggr.navigateTo('Operations', {
                        transition: 'slide',
                        reverse: false
                    });

i have used a IDE to build this app. 
    www.tiggzi.com

Comment: ok now I got what you were asking. Please add this to your actual question so you can get helped. This is a JQuery issue.

Comment: also, can we get `j_2` element (i.e. the html of this tag)?

Comment: j_2 is the header of the page. Can you please help me here?? I have to get over this soon. Any work around wold do. Thanks!!

Comment: please add in your question the html of the element/tag within the header `j_2` with the name `name="mobilenavbaritem4_141"`. This is what this jQuery is trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem and the solution.

I was using a custom jquery mobile library by tiggzi called tiggr. This was causing the error in IE.

The code was this

```
Tiggr.navigateTo('Operations', { transition: 'slide', reverse: false })
```

Now i have replaced the same with

```
window.open('Operations.html', '_self', 'width=600,height=400,toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes,resizable=yes')
```

i know this tweak with have problem during the transition, but I can move on with that.!

Thanks everyone for helping!!!